# scrapy newbie: tutorial. error when running scrapy crawl dmoz

Tags: python, scrapy

I've set up my PATH variables and I think I'm configuring everything right. But when I run the "scrapy crawl dmoz" within my startproject folder, I get these error messages:

```
c:\matt\testing\dmoz>scrapy crawl dmoz
2012-04-24 18:12:56-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.0.2841 started (bot: dmoz)
2012-04-24 18:12:56-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole,         
CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2012-04-24 18:12:56-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares:    
HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware,
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware,   
HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-04-24 18:12:56-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares:   
HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware,  DepthMiddware
2012-04-24 18:12:56-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy", line 4, in <module>
execute()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7- 
win32.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7-
win32.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7-
win32.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7-
win32.egg\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 43, in run
spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7-  
win32.egg\scrapy\spidermanager.py", line 43, in create
raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
KeyError: 'Spider not found: dmoz'
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Show the directory structure you have, the source your spider class and of settings module

Comment: choose a best answer please !

Comment: Also, the tutorial fails to mention that you ALSO need this library:
https://github.com/scrapy/queuelib

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue too.

It is because the scrapy tutorial asks you to place the spider you create in `/dmoz/spiders/` but scrapy is looking in `tutorial/tutorial/spiders`.

Save the `dmoz_spider.py` in `tutorial/tutorial/spiders` and the crawl should work.

Answer (score 0):

try in a command line

```
C:\Users\Akhtar Wahab> python # any any directory path
```

if it works

try

```
scrapy version
```

if its also working

then make sure you made scrapy project with

```
scrapy startproject name
```

if above everything is Positive for you

then make sure you are Running scraper command in a directory where `scrapy.cfg` is present .